# Why does python list slicing allow for referencing entries that aren't there?

Tags: python, slice

Consider this code:

```
>>> arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> arr[0:20]
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Why am I allowed to slice the array past `3`? I expected this to throw an an error, as there are not 20 entries to reference.

Comment: This behavior is consistent with Python list slicing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation

Comment: Answers to why questions like this require finding explanations in the development discussions.  Since this has been part of `numpy` and `python` for a long time, it will hard to find that.  It could predate the modern use of `github` and `PEP's`.

Comment: Heck, it predates the old Mercurial repository, and maybe the Subversion repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Given a slice expression like `s[i:j:k]`,

> The slice of s from i to j with step k is defined as the sequence of items with index x = i + n*k such that 0 <= n < (j-i)/k. In other words, the indices are i, i+k, i+2*k, i+3*k and so on, stopping when j is reached (but never including j). **When k is positive, i and j are reduced to len(s) if they are greater**

The same applies to numpy arrays. Given a slice expression, say `x[0:20]`, it'll just be reduced to `x[0:len(x)]` returning everything in the array.

Python gracefully handles out of bounds access to elements by returning as many elements as there are without throwing an error. This is a design decision taken by the developers of the language. You may or may not want the error, so do be cautious when slicing lists this way.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Why is it designed this way? It seems better to throw an error.

Comment: @kilojoules It is how python gracefully handles such situations _without_ throwing ugly out of bounds exceptions like other languages. It is how python was designed.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the design decision. What are the benefits of doing things this way?

Comment: @kilojoules I'm sorry... There is no official statement I am aware of, but I do believe it makes for more robust programming with the unintentional side effect now and then.

Answer (score 1):

That works for regular list slicing too, and string slicing, and tuple slicing, and most sliceable objects. It's just the Python convention to allow out-of-range slicing and adjust out-of-range slice endpoints to the nearest endpoint of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. Now I'm asking why python does this in general.